# Keeping reference data inside a DLL

Tags: c#, csv, dll, shared-libraries

I'm creating a class library, so that it can be added to future projects as a DLL to compute some data.

In order to do it's work, it needs a lot of reference data, that at the moment I have in a collection of CSV's.

When using this library in future I want it to be as easy as just adding the DLL to your project, not worrying about CSV's or Databases.

Is there an elegant solution to this? At the moment, the only thing I can think of is to hard code the data into some classes so it compiles into the DLL, but that sounds horrible, and a major maintenance pain for the future.

Comment: seem you have to either hard code the data or embed the csvs as resource.

Comment: @LeiYang How do I embed the CSV's as a resource, and does that mean that future projects don't have to deal with the CSV's?

Comment: [How to: Create Embedded Resources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2c9s1d7(v=vs.100).aspx) you'll have to release the files when dll loaded [How to embed and access resources by using Visual C#](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/319292/how-to-embed-and-access-resources-by-using-visual-c)